# Installing Python and OpenCV on Win10 64-bit

Tags: python, opencv

I want to install Python and use OpenCV with it. I am on a Windows 10 Laptop. 64-bit OS.

I am beyond confused about which version of Python and corresponding version of OpenCV to use; and how to install it.

Can someone post a small guide on how to get things working? I have been trying for weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a working configuration of Python 3.5.2 and OpenCV 3.1.0 on my Windows 10.

Download and install Python from:
https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

For OpenCV, follow:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html